# Avoiding clean failing (and hence build) from something locking a build directory

Tags: windows, ant, build

The windows cmd prompt is one culprit--I'll sometimes cd into one of my build subdirectories to check something out and unless I close down the console or cd out somewhere else, my next build is of course going to fail because it can't delete the build directories.

So sure, I can just exit the cmd prompt or cd out, but I forget and before I know it, my CI server has all these failed builds just because of this.

I can imagine there's no way Ant can force the deletion, but is there another good strategy? Can Ant be told to try to delete but not fail if it can't? I can see this might not be a good idea, but it's something I'd have to weigh up specifically for my scenario.

Or at least is there a cmd.exe option or alternative cmd line that doesn't lock the current working directory?

Answer (score 2):

Windows won't allow you to delete a directory if someone else is in that directory. It doesn't matter if its a console window or a Explorer window. There's no real way around it except by killing the process first.

What Continuous Integration tool are you using? If you're using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) or [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org) (Jenkins forked off of Hudson a few months ago) you can view the working directory by clicking on the Working Directory link on the left side of the browser window. That'll give you a view into your working directory (so you can check everything) but won't lock up the directory and prevent deletion.

If you have to get on the build machine, disable the job, so the build server won't attempt to build while you're checking things out.

Comment: I'm on Bamboo, but Windows Explorer doesn't lock a directory just by browsing in it within Explorer. Or are you saying Jenkins will allow files in that directory to be viewed without the containing directories being locked? That could be handy but still very limited compared to a command prompt. I guess what I don't understand is why command prompt has to lock a directory just because it's the current working directory. Allow another process to delete the directory and just back out to the first parent that still exists, like explorer does.

Comment: That's why I was hopping there was an alternate command prompt that doesn't lock a directory just because you're inside it.

Comment: You can in Jenkins see files without locking them because you're looking at them via a web browser. When you "view" a file in the working directory, the file is opened, the contents read, and then closed. It isn't held locked as it would be in an editor on the command line. I've never used Bamboo, but it is also web based and should have similar capabilities. This should allow you to browse the working directory without actually having to be on the build server.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think you should be logging into your build server and looking at build subdirectories so often that this is a consistent problem.  Are you working on your build on the buildserver itself? If so then you're better off making sure you can run the exact same build script from a developer machine and can work on it locally.  Consistency is key.

Beyond that, you can kill the sessions hosting the command window.  The command windows will be part of interactive sessions.  You can setup a scheduled process to find and kill inactive but left-on sessions.  Here's a good guide for doing it interactively but this can be easily scripted.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/command-line-hack-for-terminal-server-has-exceeded-the-maximum-number-of-allowed-connections/

You'll have to define your own criteria for when to auto-kill sessions.

Comment: I'm hopping into the build directory purely for the purposes of setting up a CI process. Teething problems in other words dealing with problematic and poorly documented development tools. Once I learn their peculiar ways and workarounds, I don't enter the build directories anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explore 'quiet' and 'failonerror' attributes of the ant delete task.
Be careful though.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be virus scanning that is causing you issues?  Perhaps just excluding that directory would work.